VITE/React - Struggling to get environment variables to pick up my variables set in the "secrets" section of my terraform
I'm working with a React app using VITE (for the first time) and struggling to get the variables declared in my terraform (grabbed from AWS Parameter Store) to pull through. When I set the variable in a .env file like below and run locally, the variable is set fine as I can see in the console. However when I deploy it to our QA environment (Dockerized), the console logs it as undefined, using both process.env and import.meta.env. If anyone could shed some light on what I may be doing wrong and why I would appreciate it.
I've used both the VITE_ prefix and none to the env var with no success.
.env
VITE_TEST_URL=testurlworks

vite-env.d.ts
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

declare const VITE_TEST_URL: string;

Vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

export default ({ mode }) => {
  process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) };

  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    define: {
      "process.env": process.env,
    },
    preview: {
      port: 80,
    },
    server: {
      port: 3000,
    },
  });
};

task.tf
locals {
  container_definitions = [
    {
      environment = [
        {
          name  = "ENVIRONMENT",
          value = terraform.workspace
        }
      ],
      secrets = [
        {
          "name": "VITE_TEST_URL",
          "valueFrom": "VALIDPATHTORESOURCE"
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}

App.tsx
const testUrlProcessEnv = process.env.VITE_TEST_URL;
const testUrlImportMeta = import.meta.env.VITE_TEST_URL;

console.log("VITE_TEST_URL_PROCESS_ENV", testUrlProcessEnv);
console.log("VITE_TEST_URL_IMPORT_META", testUrlImportMeta);

Dockerfile
FROM node:22-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "preview"]

I have a hunch this is an issue with VITE as we have other examples in the company of this concept working in Next.js so my last resort would be to convert this app to use Next, it's fairly small so wouldn't be too bad but obviously not ideal. I'm not sure if VITE is actually the issue or whether there is an issue in my config somewhere.
Note: I've changed var names and removed some code for security but if there is any more code you need to see let me know

It is currently unclear how the values are passed from Terraform to your React app.

Vite environment variables are set statically at build time, per the docs. Are you trying to set them at run-time?

@MatthewSchuchard After delving a bit deeper I believe they are injected into the docker container, I thought that would mean it was at build time but actually think its at run-time

@HansKilian I did think they were set at build time as they are injected into the docker container, however your comment made me look into it more after doing some digging last night I think I was mistaken and they are actually injected at run-time. I've read that VITE doesn't have support for run-time variables, are you aware of any different or is converting to nextJs going to be my best option? Thanks for the help!
